# What do I do if I forgot to pay the $30 shipping on the Ubuntu edge?

Tags: ubuntu-edge

I just paid the $600 that was automatically in the "donate" field. How do I bump it up to include shipping?

Answer (score 4):

According to Ubuntu Edge's [FAQ](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge) on the Indiegogo page, you can pay for the shipping by making another contribution and selecting the `No Perk, Just a Contribution` option. There is no need to contact Canonical.

> I contributed to a perk but I forgot to add the extra $30 for
>   shipping. How can I increase the amount?
>
> No problem! If you'd like to add funds for shipping, you can make
>   another contribution and select "No Perk, Just a Contribution."